# DB error while bootstraping Strapi App on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, strapi

While doing a deployment I am seeing this error in my Heroku build log

`error Bootstrap function in plugin "users-permissions" failed`

Note: I was able to run the application successfully before with some default PORT number. Then I changed stuff in `database.json` for both production and staging envs and since then I am not able to start the application even when I revert my changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the database you are using?

Comment: Postgres from Heroku Postgres free addon

Comment: Here is a short video of what I did and it works well - https://www.loom.com/share/835a66d8c5bb439583b7e57e51c27ccd

Comment: I forgot to answer you back. I actually made it work. I found out that I cannot use PORT to differentiate between staging and prod in the same APP on Heroku. And I have to create two separate apps. In the end I ended up using Pipelines and two separate apps using the same GIT repo but different branches. Seems to work fine. Now, I am just waiting for a native way to do data migrations between environments. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I cannot use PORT to differentiate between staging and prod in the same APP on Heroku. And I have to create two separate apps. In the end I ended up using Pipelines and two separate apps using the same GIT repo but different branches. Seems to work fine. Now, I am just waiting for a native way to do data migrations between environments.